# Why does the BIP44 derivation path generate the same address in MetaMask as the Ledger Live derivation path?

Tags: metamask, hd-wallets, mnemonic, bip39

Looking at MetaMask's [source code](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/99ed42b3dc4e1cf7fb427f433ff7cb5bda732a4f/ui/pages/create-account/connect-hardware/index.js#L25-L27) (commit [99ed42](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/99ed42b3dc4e1cf7fb427f433ff7cb5bda732a4f)), I can see that the derivation paths for Ledger Live and BIP44 differ slightly:

```js
const LEDGER_LIVE_PATH = `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`;
const BIP44_PATH = `m/44'/60'/0'/0`;
```

Ledger Live has an extra `0`.

So why do these two derivation paths generate the same address in MetaMask?

I'm getting the same address when I choose either path in the dropdown!

[image: MetaMask HD Path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extra zero indicates the key pair number derived from the master seed(commonly referred to as address_index).
You can read more about it here https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki.
The derivation path means:

```
m’ / purpose’ / coin_type’ / account’ / change / address_index
```

As you can see the last is address_index which is usually appended at the last of the master derivation path, in your case at

```
const BIP44_PATH = `m/44'/60'/0'/0`;
```

This is to generate various accounts (when you click "Generate a New Account" in MetaMask) from the same mnemonic.
So subsequent address paths would be:

```
m/44'/60'/0'/0/0  //First Account or key-pair
m/44'/60'/0'/0/1  //Second Account or key-pair
m/44'/60'/0'/0/2  //Third Account or key-pair
```

For the ledger, the first account is usually used for doing transactions, so the address with **0** for the first account is already hard-coded in the string.